# Upper bound of lattice points of $\mathbb{R}^d$ in a given annulus

Tags: abstract-algebra, integer-lattices

Suppose we have $\Gamma$ which is a lattice of $\mathbb{R}^d$ ($rk(\Gamma) = d$), and $| \cdot |$ a norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$. We consider as well $c_1, c_2 > 0$, and the annulus $S = \{ P \in \Gamma \, | \,  c_1 \leq |P| \leq c_2 \}$. How one could find a bound $\#S \leq c(c_1, c_2, \Gamma)$, if it's possible to give a "closed form" for $c(c_1, c_2, \Gamma)$ ?

Thank you !

Comment: If you mean that the bound does not depend on $\Gamma,$ there is no such bound.

Comment: @IgorRivin Sorry, I've edited my question. Clearly, it didn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: Could [this article](https://www.mmnp-journal.org/articles/mmnp/abs/2010/04/mmnp201054p293/mmnp201054p293.html) (which discusses the topic restricted to Euclidean norms) be of any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the annulus is contained in the ball of radius $c_2,$ so the asymptotic bound is the volume of the ball of radius $c_1$ divided by the covolume. This will be (possibly) way off for small radii, so if $\ell$ is the shortest vector in $\Gamma,$ then the volume of the ball divided by $\ell^d$ will work.